# Remove Read-host history after script end

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that uses read-host for user input a lot. After the script is done, and i use arrow up to go to previous script execution, i have to go through all the given answers to read-host.

Is it possible to have the read-host answers cleared somehow?

Comment: PowreShell >= 5.0 supports reverse command search using `ctrl`  `R`

Comment: Not exactly what i mean.When entering the read-host values, once the script is finished, when i press up arrow, i want to be back at the .\psscript.ps1 -switch and i dont want to go through all the read-host values i used.

Comment: Sure, it's clear that this is not what you meant. It is a hint to a very productive alternative to narrow-up-ping commands

Comment: I guess you are hinting to F7 or F8?

Comment: No, Ctrl + R, just as I said. It's similiar to F7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Clear-History` cmdlet to remove items from your history, allowing you to simply press up and run the command again.  Suppose you have 3 `Read-Host` lines in your code, at the end of your script you can add the following line in order to clear the history that `Read-Host` took:

`Clear-History -Newest 3`

Alternatively, in case your Read-Host lines are surrounded by conditional statements, you could simply put a `Clear-History -Command "Read-Host"` which would remove all lines with `Read-Host` from your history.